# Bamboo infinite loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bitbucket, bamboo, engineyard

Having some major issues with Bamboo.

I run a rails project, that runs on Engine Yard.

My build strategy is as follows

1. Checkout from Source Code
2. bundle install
3. rspec (run tests)
4. Tag my build

(code to create tag causes new commit, tag used in deploy)

```
git remote remove origin 
git remote add origin <my repo> 
git tag Bamboo-${bamboo.buildNumber}
git push origin Bamboo-${bamboo.buildNumber}
```

In my deploy the way engine yard works is you deploy based on branches or tags ( there is no build artifacts)

So in my Deploy it's a single script that uses a gem https://github.com/engineyard/engineyard

and runs

```
ey deploy --environment <staging> --tag=Bamboo- ${bamboo.buildNumber} --app <my app>
```

Engine yard does all the rails 'stuff' to prep the build and deploy it. Really just need Bamboo to run test and if it works tag build.

**PROBLEM**

I am using bitbucket source control and have configured a hook to trigger a bamboo build on any commit to master.

The issue step 4) is pushing a tag which causes bitbucket to execute another build

**Resulting in infinitely building bamboo.**

Looking into how to solve this. Figured I could use Bamboo 'Exclude Changesets' and filter out a particular commit message

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Bitbucket?focusedCommentId=610435557&#comment-610435557

so my 4) would now look like

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin <my repo>

#create tag
git tag -a Bamboo-${bamboo.buildNumber} - m 'bamboo build'
#push tag
git push origin Bamboo-${bamboo.buildNumber}
```

However as per the comments on that confluence page. Exclude Changsets isn't a visible option anymore?

I don't understand how I can stop this infinite building loop.

Answer (score 0):

We use Bamboo and a tag doesn't kick off the build for us.

Our tag process is:

```
git tag -a v1.4.2 -m 'Production Release: [date]
git push origin --tags
```

Try using the `--tags` option when pushing.